# How to extend basic manager in django?

Tags: python, django, methods

How to add custom method to the basic django manager?

```
ModelNmame.objects.custom_method()
```

Comment: You subclass the manager, and add that manager to your `ModelName`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods

Comment: as per @WillemVanOnsem comment above, I think you're looking for a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an subclass for Manager and assign it to the objects attribute of your model

```
class CustomManger(models.Manager):
   def custom_method(self):
      pass

class ModelName(models.Model):
   objects = CustomManager()
```

Comment: Django docs link to custom mangers - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/
refer this for more